# Loading local html file from asset folder into a webview

Tags: android, webview

Trouble in loading local html file from asset into a webview. HTML page has javascript code, so I have used webview.setJavaScriptEnabled(true) to enable it. It loads the html page, but not all the widgets properly. Any suggestions...

Comment: please share the code, so we can see if you are missing something.

Comment: you need to fill 3 important things, i.e. HTML data/file, Mimetype & encoding to make the webview understand it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class ViewWeb extends Activity {  

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.webview);  
            WebView wv;  
            wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hello.html");   
        }  
    }
```

Comment: I did exactly the same, and even enabled the Javascript for the webview. But, I have a folder which has an HTML page and many javascript files linked to it. It displays the HTML page but, rendering the images is not happening properly.